# WTL Error: RegisterClassObjects(DWORD,DWORD) throw()' already has a body

Tags: c++

I am having a compiling error I just don't understand.  I have two C++ projects that use the WLT 8.0.  I am using VS2005 to compile both.  One runs on Win XP or 7, and the other on CE.  They both include the WLT 8.0 headers.

But when compiling for the CE project I get the following error:

```
Error 104 error C2084: function 'HRESULT ATL::CComModule::RegisterClassObjects(DWORD,DWORD) throw()' already has a body C:\WTL80\include\atlapp.h 150
```

The source for this error is here:

```
namespace ATL
{
  inline HRESULT CComModule::RegisterClassObjects(DWORD /*dwClsContext*/, DWORD /*dwFlags*/) throw()
  { return E_NOTIMPL; }
  inline HRESULT CComModule::RevokeClassObjects() throw()
  { return E_NOTIMPL; }
}; // namespace ATL
```

Only thing I can see that is different between the two projects are these marcos in the CE project: `(_WIN32_WCE=$(CEVER);ARM;_ARM_;$(CePlatform);ARMV4I;UNDER_CE=$(CEVER);)`, and I can not set the default calling convention of `__cdecl` in the CE project.

Anyone have a clue would love the education.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an incompatibility between WTL's `atlapp.h` and ATL's `atlbase.h`. It will only happen on WinCE projects `#ifdef _WIN32_WCE`. So, I think the answer is to comment out the broken WTL section.

In atlapp.h

```
// namespace ATL
// {
//   inline HRESULT CComModule::RegisterClassObjects(DWORD /*dwClsContext*/, DWORD /*dwFlags*/) throw()
//   { return E_NOTIMPL; }
//   inline HRESULT CComModule::RevokeClassObjects() throw()
//   { return E_NOTIMPL; }
// }; // namespace ATL
```

This part of WTL was probably an attempt to supplement an earlier version of ATL and was just not removed when ATL came up to speed.

-PaulH

Answer (score 1):

`CComModule::RegisterClassObjects()` and `CComModule::RevokeClassObjects()` only defined if `_CE_DCOM` is so:

```
#if !defined (_CE_DCOM)
namespace ATL
{
  inline HRESULT CComModule::RegisterClassObjects(DWORD /*dwClsContext*/, DWORD /*dwFlags*/) throw()
  { return E_NOTIMPL; }
  inline HRESULT CComModule::RevokeClassObjects() throw()
  { return E_NOTIMPL; }
}; // namespace ATL
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed my answer.
Did some googling and found out that CE does not support`CComModule::RegisterClassObjects` and `CComModule::RevokeClassObjects`.

Therefor I think that you somehow link against a standard windows library which does contain those functions (check your libs) or you use an object-file from a previous (not CE) build (Rebuild project).

EDIT: There's one thing that came to mind. When you're using pre-compiled-headers and it contains #include  and in your source file you also include atlapp.h then maybe this could cause such an error.

Comment: That can't be the problem. If I remove the atlapp.h file I get this error:

Error 12 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atlapp.h'.  

The initial error says it already has a body.  My guess is I don't know what I need to add to the compiler so it knows how to handle the throw() after the parameters and before the body.

Comment: The error clearly states that **ATL::CComModule::RegisterClassObjects(DWORD,DWORD) throw()** already has a body. It is defined in the ATL-library. If you remove those functions (comment them out) and make a call to them ,you will not get an unresolved error (indicating that is defined). You might redefine them (but I doubt if it will work) by enabling function level-linking for your linker.

Comment: To my knowledge I am not including the ATL-library other than what is in the WTL.  Do you know a way I can verify that?

Comment: What I know about it is that WTL is an extension to ATL So IMO it can't be used without it. If you can specify /VERBOSE to your link-cmd you'll get a list of all the libraries that are searched.

Comment: @ Chauncat: Is the code fragment your code or is it from a wtl-header-file ?

Comment: Yes that is why I was so confused.

Comment: @Chauncat: Well try a full rebuild and if that doesn't work check your libraries with the /VERBOSE option of your linker. If that doesn't give you clues to what is wrong ,I suggest search the internet for ducumentation. I read something about "WTL documentation project" ,maybe that will help. Sorry I couldn't help much.

Comment: @Edwin:  I think I am down the right path so far.  Thank you so much.  It has been a nightmare update this Embedded Visual C++ project

Comment: @Chauncat: I'd like to known what your solution was/is. Might be helpfull to others too ,when they encounter similar problem.

Comment: I am still having issue with this project.  But this issue was corrected by you suggestion of commenting out the code.  I could not live it commented out because I use these same headers for projects may use the section commented out.  So I changed it to look like this

#ifndef CEPLATFORM
namespace ATL
{
  inline HRESULT CComModule::RegisterClassObjects(DWORD /*dwClsContext*/, DWORD /*dwFlags*/) throw()
  { return E_NOTIMPL; }
  inline HRESULT CComModule::RevokeClassObjects() throw()
  { return E_NOTIMPL; }
}; // namespace ATL
#endif

Comment: And define CEPLATFORM in my CE project.  Thanks again for the help.  Don't understand whey I didn't have to do this when the project was compiled with Microsoft Embedded Visual C++. Although it got me pass this issue so thank you so much for your time.